# Fusuma 4-finger gestures not working

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, gestures

I'm trying to use fusuma 4 finger gesture to minimize windows and change between them.
I edited the config.yml file and checked in the terminal, running fusuma command, if gestures were being recognized, and they are, but no action is executed.

2 and 3 finger gestures work just fine

Here there are my config file and fusuma output

[fusuma --version output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbAeD.png)
[config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB3Fy.png)
[fusuma output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmhYT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please paste output of `fusuma --version`.

If you are using Wayland, you should try `fusuma-plugin-sendkey`.

Comment: tried that but says "command not found"

Comment: You need to install plugin. https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma-plugin-sendkey